# What exactly happens after a sql transaction fails in android?

Tags: android

If you are using transactions and the sql operation fails, I know that it rolls back all the changes, but will it then halt all code after the finally statement or will the rest continue to run?

Does something like the below code look right or should I be using a catch statement? And is it possible to simulate an error for testing purposes?

```
public static boolean updateSuccessful = false;

updateToVersion2();
//Does anything after here still run on error?

if(!updateSuccessful) {
    deleteAndRecreateDatabase();
}


public void updateToDbVersion2() {
    this.myDataBase.beginTransaction();
    try {
        this.myDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE myRecords SET column = 'newValue1' WHERE _id = 1");
        this.myDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE myRecords SET column = 'newValue2' WHERE _id = 2");
        this.myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        // This is not reached on update error, right?
        updateSuccessful = true;
    } finally {
        this.myDataBase.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transaction acts as a whole itself. Either it is successful or it fails, that means that either you get all your data in DB or you get nothing (within this transaction of course).
If the transaction fails at some point, it should go first to the "catch" part and to "finally" after.

As user827992 points, it'll be interesting to catch exceptions. There could be some extra (maybe valuable) information there.

Comment: So there's nothing extra special going on. It will fail just like any other error, but if you use transactions, it won't commit partial changes to the db.

Comment: Yes, but still it's recommendable to use them. Note that a single transaction is opened for each operation in the DB. This process is taking most of the time of the operation. If you commit 20 changes to your db outside of the same transaction, the processing time will be multiplied by 20. If you include all of them within the same transaction it'll take just some milliseconds more.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was thinking it was more complex than it actually is.

Answer (score 1):

You should be catching the exception! Why you left it out makes the code smell bad...

What if an exception did indeed occur between `execSQL` and `setTransactionSuccessful` and eventually falls into the `finally` part where you end the transaction?

The code could be something like this:

```
public void updateToDbVersion2() {
    boolean fubar = false;
    this.myDataBase.beginTransaction();
    try {
        this.myDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE myRecords SET column = 'newValue1' WHERE _id = 1");
        this.myDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE myRecords SET column = 'newValue2' WHERE _id = 2");
        this.myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        // This is not reached on update error, right?
        updateSuccessful = true;
    } catch(Exception ex){
        fubar = true;
        // Do whatever is needed to be done such as logcat FOR debugging ONLY!
    } finally {
        if (!fubar){
            // No exceptions occurred, OK to end transaction
            this.myDataBase.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the conditional check on the `finally` clause ensures prevention of potential mess as a result and ensures data integrity.

Comment: Is this necessary? My understanding is that finally will always run and if endTransaction is reached without setTransactionSuccessful, it will rollback the transaction

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of exceptions

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/SQLException.html

and some related example and suggestions around the web

[Android Database error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598461/android-database-error)

[Why doesn't SQLException catch SQLiteExcpetion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159809/why-doesnt-sqlexception-catch-sqliteexcpetion)